# jquery autocomplete brings wrong results on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

here's the array. If i type the letter **l** in the box **lol** should be the first result, instead **calculator** is.

```
var src = [
    "actionScript",
    "calculator",
    "asp",
    "bASIC",
    "lol",
    "c++",
    "clojure",
    "cOBOL",
    "malstrom",
    "erlang",
    "caltronic",
    "groovy",
    "haskell",
    "java",
    "javaScript",
    "lisp",
    "perl",
    "php",
    "python",
    "ruby",
    "scala",
    "scheme"];

$("#auto").autocomplete({ 
    source: src
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqwBP/494/

I guess it's because it detects an l in calculator but I think it should first display results starting with l. No? Is there any way to correct this behaviour ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because calculator matches and it is in the list first.

If you want to match based on starts with
Use

```
    // Overrides the default autocomplete filter function to search only from the beginning of the string
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
        return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
```

http://blog.miroslavpopovic.com/jqueryui-autocomplete-filter-words-starting-with-term

Or you can write whatever kind of matching scheme you want inside this function.